# How to add a div on button click?

Tags: jquery, html, asp-classic

I have a button "Add" on click the button it should display two textbox along with two images ,on clicking the image calendar pop up occurs.The problem for me is when i click the add button nothing happens.can anyone teel whay i have done wrongly.Please provide an example if possible and is it possible do this in javascript instead of jquery.thanks in advance

This what i have tried

```js
$("#btnAddAddress").click(function () {
    var addelement=$('<div class= "one"> <table> <tr> <td> <asp:Label ID="lblStartDate" runat="server" Text="Start Date"> </asp:Label> </td> <td> <asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox> <asp:HyperLink ID="hypCalenStart" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/ico-cal.gif"> </asp:HyperLink> <ajax:CalendarExtender ID="StartDatePicker" runat="server" PopupButtonID="hypCalenStart" TargetControlID="txtStartDate"  SelectedDate= "<%# Datetime.Today()%>" Format="MM/dd/yyyy"> </ajax:CalendarExtender> </td> <td> <asp:Label ID="lblEndDate" runat="server" Text="End Date"></asp:Label></td></tr></table></div>');
    $(this).after(addelement);
});
```

```html
<div class="button">
    <input type="button" id="btnAddAddress" name="btnAddAddress" value="Add"  />
</div>
```

> Error: Unable to get value of the property '_behaviors': object is null or undefined

Comment: you can't add server controls using jquery.

Comment: @Learner:is there any other way to do add a div?

Comment: try html controls here is example http://jsfiddle.net/hfo1r2aj/

Answer (score 1):

Well, one thing you can do is to add a class defined through CSS... for your specific case, you could add something like this:

```
$("#btnAddAddress").click(function(){
    $("#times").removeClass("hidden");
    $("#times").addClass("one");
});
```

[...]

```
<style>
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
</style>
```

Then, in your page, add the id "times" to the `div` that you want to appear, and have it initially with the "hidden" class instead of "one" ("hidden" is replaced by "one" when you click the button)... it's a little simple, but it should work.

`display` functionality seen [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp).